# Goal: Display different lightning pages for users in same profile but with different permission set

Tags: lightning, profile, permission-sets

There are two lightning pages A & B. I want to display the lightning page based on the permission set but all the users belong to the same profile. How can I achieve this?

Account object -> Lightning page A, Lightning page B

Profile - Demo profile

Permission sets : C & D

Now users with in demo profile with permission set C should see Page A.
Users with demo profile with permission sets C & D should see Page B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Layouts are determined by Record Type and Profile, not Permission Set. you'd have to use separate profiles to enable this, even if they are just clones with different page layout assignments.

Comment: Ohkay. That makes sense. So, what I am trying to achieve here is to hide a tab on a page. This tab has to be hidden if the user does not have a specific permission set. 

Instead of doing that, I though of creating two-page layouts and displays based on the permission set. But can we hide a tab, based on permission set?

Comment: @JasonCastle Permissions *add* permission, not *remove* it. The solution would be to create a Custom Permission, add that Custom Permission to a Permission Set, then use the Lightning App Builder to build the app in a way where you check for this custom permission.